# Word for combination of strength and agility

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a way to call an attribute for a Pen&Paper RPG.
It's supposed to be derived from "Strength" and "Agilty" and would be used for all kinds of things which usually fall somewhere in between, like swimming, climbing, jumping, etc.
So far, I am stuck with **athleticism** and I was also wondering whether **sportiness** might be an option or whether that's usually used for "fairness in sports". But both feel a little unwieldy compared to other attribute names.
Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an RPG player attribute, I think "**conditioning**", "**vigor**", and "**might**" all work pretty well.

Comment: I'm accepting this because I also thought of using vigor. Still struggling to decide between athleticism and that.

Answer (score 2):

**Prowess** might be a good single word choice. You can be more descriptive by using **physical prowess**.

Merriam-Webster offers this definition: 
"extraordinary ability" and "He is know for his prowess on the football field." shown as an example in a sentence.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to avoid using multiple words for attribute names and without the "physical" qualifier, prowess doesn't seem to express the intended meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word ‘fitness’ might be what you’re looking for.

Definition of [‘fit’](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fit) from Lexico:

> In good health, especially because of regular physical exercise

The word ‘fitness’ brings athletes to mind and athletes make me think of training that focuses on both strength and agility (think football, soccer, gymnastics, etc.). I believe the word ‘fitness’ would suit a game skill that directly relates to swimming, climbing, jumping, etc.

Comment: +1 for fitness.  Hardy doesn't really imply agility or dexterity. Shrubs and soups are hardy. Neither of them has ever jumped out of my way.

Comment: @David M: Ha, agreed. When I saw ‘fit’, as in ‘fitness’, I was like ‘That’s it.’ But, that was after I’d already finished my answer. As for ‘hardy’, it was the definition that made me think it was suitable, because of the activities that OP said the skill would apply to, though I agree that agility wouldn’t really come to mind when seeing the word by itself.

Comment: Now that I’m rethinking it, by itself, ‘hardy’ is more like the survival skill from Fallout. This is actually the first time I’ve answered a question on here. Do you think I should edit my answer, so that it includes ‘fitness’ alone? Or should I delete and post a new answer?

Comment: Dealer's choice. I'd say it's not been downvoted to hell. Edit away.

Answer (score 2):

[**Physicality**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/physicality) might fit the bill here.

> The physical attributes of a person, especially when overdeveloped or overemphasized.

Otherwise, I'd elect to use the global term **fitness**.  Someone who is fit is a good combination of strong and dextrous.